# How to create a delete trigger on a table containing records older than X days in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table named `global_notif` which has  two columns `date` (DATE) and `notifications` (TEXT).The date format is shown as YYYY-MM-DD. 
Now, i want to apply a trigger that will delete all the records older than 2 days.
So i have written this definition:

```
DELETE FROM global_notif
WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

The screenshot of the window is as follows:[phpmyadmin trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtYxP.png)
After clicking go,it shows that trigger is set successfully.
The problem is, it dosen't work at all.However when i run the above query separately, the query runs fine and deletes desired records.
So, i would like to know that why this trigger is not deleteing the records.Also,if someone can tell me that will this BEFORE DELETE trigger even work for what i want to do.
Thanks.

Comment: If doesn't seem to make sense to have a trigger BEFORE delete on a table that in itself deletes from the table (hence triggering itself to delete, etc). I think MySQL would block this (I would hope so, to avoid an endless loop) but I would expect an error message

Comment: Can you please suggest me any other efficient way of deleting records from the table on its own?

Comment: Not really easily possible. MySQL does support timed execution of queries, although I have never used them (not sure they are enabled in most MySQL installations). Your trigger would only be fired off when a record is manually deleted (ie, if a record is deleted). If it is a regularly added to up updated table and you just want to delete old records then you would probably be best having the delete associated with the insert trigger.

Comment: Read [MySQL Event Scheduler Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html). [Relevant posts on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a767881%20%5bmysql%5d%20event%20scheduler)

Comment: @RavinderReddy I also tried using event scheduler but that too didn't work :(

Comment: Go through my referred posts. They explain in detail on what you need to set or check to have events working.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger is use for any action done in any table then you would like to do operation. 
But for your case it is better to use stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `deleteNotification`(X INT)
BEGIN

   DELETE FROM global_notif
   WHERE (global_notif.date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL X DAY));

END;
```

Please create above stored procedure and then call this procedure by using below query.

```
CALL deleteNotification(2);
```

In above query 2 is no of days.

Comment: Making a stored procedure for such a trivial task is a waste of time and effort.

Comment: when i executed the second statement, the following error showed up.
`#1442 - Can't update table 'global_notif' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: @me.ydv.5 - I assume you have tried to call this procedure from the before delete trigger? As that is the message I would expect MySQL to issue.